# Update values of sliderInputs

Tags: r, shiny

I have tried to read from saved values of interconnected sliderInputs but somehow only the value of the first slider is correct.
The three sliderInputs must sum to 100. I tried to relate the second and third sliders to the first one. The code makes the idea clear.

Can you see the error?
Here is my code:

```
ui <- 
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(
      title = 'Test'),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
      sliderInput(inputId = 'Envr', 
                  label = "Environment", 
                  min = 0, 
                  max = 100, 
                  value = 100, 
                  step = 1
      ),
      uiOutput(
        outputId = 'secondInputUI'
      ),
      uiOutput(
        outputId = 'thirdInputUI'
      ),
      selectInput(inputId = 'fourthInput', 
                  label = "Combination", 
                  choices = c("23_46_31","90_8_2","100_0_0"), 
                  selected = "100_0_0", 
                  multiple = F
      )
    )
  )
server <- function(input, output, session){
    output$secondInputUI <- renderUI({
      sliderInput(inputId = "Dist",label = "Distance",min = 0,max = 100 - input$Envr,value = 100 - input$Envr)
    })
    output$thirdInputUI <- renderUI({
      sliderInput(inputId = "Hist",label = "History",min = 0,max = 100 - input$Envr - input$Dist,value = 100 - input$Envr - input$Dist)
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$fourthInput, {
      values <- stringr::str_split(input$fourthInput,pattern = "_")  %>% unlist(x = ) %>% as.numeric()
      
      updateSliderInput(session = session,inputId = "Envr",min = 0, max = 100,value = values[1])
      updateSliderInput(session = session,inputId = "Dist",min = 0,max = 100 - values[1],value = values[2])
      updateSliderInput(session = session,inputId = "Hist",min = 0,max = 100 - values[1] - values[2],value = values[3])
    })
    
  }
  
shinyApp(
  ui = ui,
  server = server)
```

Comment: But how can trigger the changes in the state of the selectInput widget.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution to do it in case someone need such solution.

```
    ui <- 
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(
      title = 'Test'),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
      sliderInput(inputId = 'Envr', 
                  label = "Environment", 
                  min = 0, 
                  max = 100, 
                  value = 100, 
                  step = 1
      ),
      uiOutput(
        outputId = 'secondInputUI'
      ),
      uiOutput(
        outputId = 'thirdInputUI'
      ),
      selectInput(inputId = 'fourthInput', 
                  label = "Combination", 
                  choices = c("23_46_31","90_8_2","100_0_0"), 
                  selected = "100_0_0", 
                  multiple = F
      )
    )
  )
server <- function(input, output, session){
    
  output$secondInputUI <- renderUI({
    sliderInput(inputId = "Dist",label = "Distance",min = 0,max = 100 - input$Envr,value = 100 - input$Envr)
  })
  
  output$thirdInputUI <- renderUI({
    sliderInput(inputId = "Hist",label = "History",min = 0,max = 100 - input$Envr - input$Dist,value = 100 - input$Envr - input$Dist)
  })
    
    observeEvent(input$fourthInput, {
      
      values <- stringr::str_split(input$fourthInput,pattern = "_")  %>% unlist(x = ) %>% as.numeric()
      updateSliderInput(session = session,inputId = "Envr",min = 0, max = 100,value = values[1])

      output$secondInputUI <- renderUI({
        sliderInput(inputId = "Dist",label = "Distance",min = 0,max = 100 - values[1],value = values[2])
      })
      output$thirdInputUI <- renderUI({
        sliderInput(inputId = "Hist",label = "Distance",min = 0,max = 100 - values[1] - values[2],value = values[3])
      })

    })
    
  }
  
shinyApp(
  ui = ui,
  server = server)
```